# Why is the location of the format string on stack so different on different linux systems?

Tags: c

When you call a function like printf, the formatstring and the arguments are pushed onto the stack. If you ommit the parameters but specify them in the format string with "%x" or "%s" or "%n" you cann access (read or write) the formatstring. On one system i testet that, the format string was the 4th argument. On another it was beyond the 200th.

For example, i got the following program that is vulnerable to a formatstring exploit and contains the following statement:

```
printf(userSuppliedString);
```

No I want to read a specific adress. For example. 0xbffffdd7.
I call it the following way:

```
./fmt_vuln $(printf "\xd7\xfd\xff\xbf")%08x.%08x.%08x.%s
```

In this example the format string is the fourth parameter ("%s"). So %s will take the beginning of the format string. Because this is the adress we specified the content of this adress will be printed.

Now on this machine the formatstring is the fourth paraemter. But on other linux systems its something totaly different. 
Why is that so?

Comment: Can you provide some example code to illustrate your question?

Comment: Are you talking about the location of the *content* of the string? All that's passed on the stack is a *pointer* to the string (i.e., the address at which it's allocated). For varargs functions, parameters are normally pushed right to left so it'll be at the top of the stack (so `printf` can always find the first argument).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> When you call a function like printf, the formatstring and the
>   arguments are pushed onto the stack. If you ommit the parameters but
>   specify them in the format string with "%x" or "%s" or "%n" you cann
>   access (read or write) the formatstring. On one system i testet that,
>   the format string was the 4th argument. On another it was beyond the
>   200th.

No, perhaps you have misunderstood.

When you call printf with one argument - the format string, a pointer to the format string is pushed onto the stack. This is a `char *` This pointer can point to anywhere in memory - printf just does at it is told and reads that memory location as a format string.

In the usual one argument case, you pass a string literal to `printf ("hello world!");` The compiler puts the text `hello world` somewhere in memory, and generates a pointer to it to pass to printf. Then it does whatever the calling conventions say it should do for a function call - for example on x86 it pushes the pointer to the stack. Printf then reads its first argument from the stack and is happy!

In the usual n argument case, the same thing happens with the string literal and the pointer. For the function call, the compiler passes each of the values. Again using x86 (Because pushing is easier to describe than, say, ARM which has a complicated argument passing scheme) These values are pushed to the stack from right to left. So if you have a call to `printf ("%d, %s, %d", x, name, y);` y is pushed to the stack, then name, x, and finally the format string.

Now, inside printf we read our first argument (get it from the stack). It is a `char *` pointing to `"%d, %s, %d"`. We can read this, and then - knowing how the compiler passes arguments we can read the three things which were pushed to the stack - Again we are happy!

The format string vulnerability works by misaligning the belief printf has and the belief which the compiler has.

We can show it by invoking the undefined behaviour caused by passing the wrong number of arguments to printf. in the call `printf ("%s");` The compiler does not push the argument which would correspond to the `char *` printf expects to use to fulfil the `%s` directive. But - because printf doesn't know the compiler didn't do it it looks for the argument on the stack anyway. It pulls an undefined value off the stack and attempts to read the string it points to.

In your case you allow arbitrary format strings to be passed to printf. These certainly have a mismatch between the number of arguments expected and the number of arguments passed, and so printf reads the stack - which is filled with junk.

If you are lucky - you can manipulate this junk to point to something you control - and can use this to read information you were not expecting. If you can trick a %n argument to point to somewhere you control, you can write to that memory location with the number of characters printed.

So - with this description in mind I can't find a way to parse your question which makes sense. Perhaps you can be more clear and I can update my answer?

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> ./fmt_vuln $(printf "\xd7\xfd\xff\xbf")%08x.%08x.%08x.%s
> ```
>
> In this example the format string is the fourth parameter ("%s").

No, not really. The problem is you are not accessing the fourth parameter of `printf`, instead, you are accessing a local variable or parameter in its calling function (or further up the stack). Therefore, it depends entirely on the code of the calling function. For a demonstration what does it do on a 386:

```
Breakpoint 1, __printf (format=0xbffff543 "%p") at printf.c:29
29      printf.c: Adresář nebo soubor neexistuje.
        in printf.c
(gdb) x/120a $ebp

Description:    $esp            return addr             fmtstring       parameters

0xbffff2d8:     0xbffff2f8      0x80483fd <main+25>     0xbffff543      0xb7ff1310
0xbffff2e8:     0x804842b <__libc_csu_init+11>  0xb7fb7ff4      0x8048420 <__libc_csu_init>     0x0
0xbffff2f8:     0xbffff378      0xb7e78e46 <__libc_start_main+230>      0x2     0xbffff3a4
0xbffff308:     0xbffff3b0      0xb7fe1860      0xb7ff7411      0xffffffff
0xbffff318:     0xb7ffeff4      0x8048254       0x1     0xbffff360
0xbffff328:     0xb7ff0996      0xb7fffac0      0xb7fe1b58      0xb7fb7ff4
0xbffff338:     0x0     0x0     0xbffff378      0xa32ae5c4
0xbffff348:     0x93d0f3d4      0x0     0x0     0x0
0xbffff358:     0x2     0x8048330 <_start>      0x0     0xb7ff65b0
0xbffff368:     0xb7e78d6b <__libc_start_main+11>       0xb7ffeff4      0x2     0x8048330 <_start>
0xbffff378:     0x0     0x8048351 <_start+33>   0x80483e4 <main>        0x2
0xbffff388:     0xbffff3a4      0x8048420 <__libc_csu_init>     0x8048410 <__libc_csu_fini>     0xb7ff1310
0xbffff398:     0xbffff39c      0xb7fff908      0x2     0xbffff539
0xbffff3a8:     0xbffff543      0x0     0xbffff546      0xbffff55a
0xbffff3b8:     0xbffff56a      0xbffff581      0xbffff58c      0xbffff5dc
0xbffff3c8:     0xbffff5f3      0xbffff654      0xbffff66f      0xbffff689
```

As you can see, the format string is only present further in memory, in the area initialized by the libc runtime, where `argv` points to. You have to study the code you're attacking better.